# Aptana PHP Code Analisys Quick Fix

Tags: php, aptana

Does Aptana 3 have any plugin to provide Code Analisys Quick Fix like Eclipse does on Java?

I would like to write a method or a property and have Aptana to advertise me that this method/property doesn't exist and provide me with the automatic creation of this.

like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkmCk.png